# Show index values in JSON when serializing a list

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class containing a list of items.  When I serialize the class I would like the item index values to appear in the JSON.

I am using following code to convert into JSON:

```
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imp);
```

Right now I am getting the output shown below:

```
{
    "userdata":{
        "name":"name",
        "type":"type",
        "company_name":"company_name"
    },
    "f_item":null,
    "o_item":null,
    "attributes":[
        {
            "firstval":"0",
            "name":"at 0",
            "opposite_name":"opname 0"
        },
        {
            "firstval":"1",
            "name":"at 1",
            "opposite_name":"opname 1"
        },
        {
            "firstval":"2",
            "name":"at 2",
            "opposite_name":"opname 2"
        },
        {
            "firstval":"3",
            "name":"at 3",
            "opposite_name":"opname 3"
        },
        {
            "firstval":"4",
            "name":"at 4",
            "opposite_name":"opname 4"
        }
    ],
    "eos":null
}
```

I need output like this instead:

```
{
    "userdata":{
        "name":"name",
        "type":"type",
        "company_name":"company_name"
    },
    "f_item":null,
    "o_item":null,
    "attributes":{
        "0": {
            "firstval":"0",
            "name":"at 0",
            "opposite_name":"opname 0"
        },
        "1": {
            "firstval":"1",
            "name":"at 1",
            "opposite_name":"opname 1"
        },
        "2": {
            "firstval":"2",
            "name":"at 2",
            "opposite_name":"opname 2"
        },
        "3": {
            "firstval":"3",
            "name":"at 3",
            "opposite_name":"opname 3"
        },
        "4": {
            "firstval":"4",
            "name":"at 4",
            "opposite_name":"opname 4"
        }
    },
    "eos":null
}
```

How can I configure Json.Net to output the index values?

Comment: That is not a valid json object that you are trying to make. Try any of the available online json formaters to test your solution. https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ for example.

Comment: *attributes* itself is an array of objects. So you can easily loop through it using its index. Why would you want to specify it's key with the index though it's already indexed internally.

Comment: So your question is: how should your "imp" object look for it to be converted it into your desired json?

Comment: I hope the current json output is pretty clear what i have in imp object, and if yes, then you are right

Comment: @AshadShanto I dont want to create string in looping

Comment: Be careful of the XY problem when asking questions. You want to know how to get from an array of objects to a specific json structure. Not how to configure Json.Net to do it. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Instead of trying to configure Json.Net to output the data in a non standard way, try to use the proper data structure instead. As a much simpler solution, use a Dictionary to store the content of your array. Json.Net will interpret it as an object and will use each key as properties for it.

```
var originalArray = new [] {
    new { Foo = "first",  Bar = "abc" },
    new { Foo = "second", Bar = "def" },
    new { Foo = "third",  Bar = "ghi" },
    new { Foo = "fourth", Bar = "jkl" }
};

var data = originalArray
    .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
    .ToDictionary(wrapper => wrapper.index, wrapper => wrapper.value);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

This sample code will output the following JSON, which is just what you want:

```
{
    "0": {"Foo":"first",  "Bar":"abc"},
    "1": {"Foo":"second", "Bar":"def"},
    "2": {"Foo":"third",  "Bar":"ghi"},
    "3": {"Foo":"fourth", "Bar":"jkl"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of items in your class but you need your JSON output to be formatted as an object with indexed properties (rather than an array), you can use a custom `JsonConverter` to convert the list into an object during serialization.

Here is what the converter might look like.  This will work for anything that implements `ICollection`, which includes lists and arrays.

```
class ListToObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        int index = 0;
        foreach (object item in (ICollection)value)
        {
            jo.Add(index.ToString(), JToken.FromObject(item, serializer));
            index++;
        }
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to the `attributes` property in your class like this:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ListToObjectConverter))]
    public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
```

Then, just serialize like you normally would, and you will get the output you want.  Here is a demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RootObject imp = new RootObject
        {
            userdata = new UserData
            {
                name = "name",
                type = "type",
                company_name = "company_name"
            },
            attributes = new List<Attribute>
            {
                new Attribute
                {
                    firstval = "0",
                    name = "at 0",
                    opposite_name = "oppname 0"
                },
                new Attribute
                {
                    firstval = "1",
                    name = "at 1",
                    opposite_name = "oppname 1"
                },
                new Attribute
                {
                    firstval = "2",
                    name = "at 2",
                    opposite_name = "oppname 2"
                }
            }
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imp, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public UserData userdata { get; set; }
    public object f_item { get; set; }
    public object o_item { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ListToObjectConverter))]
    public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
    public object eos { get; set; }
}

public class UserData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string company_name { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public string firstval { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string opposite_name { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "userdata": {
    "name": "name",
    "type": "type",
    "company_name": "company_name"
  },
  "f_item": null,
  "o_item": null,
  "attributes": {
    "0": {
      "firstval": "0",
      "name": "at 0",
      "opposite_name": "oppname 0"
    },
    "1": {
      "firstval": "1",
      "name": "at 1",
      "opposite_name": "oppname 1"
    },
    "2": {
      "firstval": "2",
      "name": "at 2",
      "opposite_name": "oppname 2"
    }
  },
  "eos": null
}
```